# Python subprocess doesn't recognize commands in $PATH

Tags: php, python, shell

I'm trying to debug a sublime plugin that stopped working all of the sudden.

I have the following code in the plugin.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, startupinfo=info, cwd=home)
data = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Basically, it's executing a file that has `#!/usr/bin/env php` at the top. When I run the command, I get `env: php: no such file or directory` error message.

I fixed it by using absolute path.

**Solution 1**: #!/usr/bin/env /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/bin/php

While this works, I really wonder why it doesn't work when **php** is available when I execute it in my terminal and the path to the command is defined in $PATH variable.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) you need to pass `shell=True`, as an argument to `subprocess.Popen`:

> If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes, filename wildcards, **environment variable expansion**, and expansion of ~ to a user’s home directory.

Though the use of `shell=True` is discourged [due to security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).

Comment: The problem is that it seems like it's working for everyone, except me. I don't see any complains from the plugin repository. When I pass shell=True, it doesn't actually pass additional arguments to the file.

Comment: @Moon does `declare -p PATH` in your terminal start with `declare -x`? If not, your path is not exported and that's why it fails.

Comment: @Moon for whatever reason `call(['ls', '-l'], shell=True)` does *not* pass the `-l` argument but `call('ls -l', shell=True)` and `call(['/bin/ls', '-l'])` do. so if you are passing `shell=True`, then the command should be a string, not a list.

Comment: @behzad.nouri Thank you so much. I will test them out soon.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the documentation. `shell=True` allows you to access variables with the `$variable` notation, which is a shell feature. Having access to the environment and thus the `PATH` are OS features which do not require `shell=True`. Separately, `['ls', '-l'], shell=True` ends up running `sh -c 'ls' _ '-l'` because that's what `shell=True` does on Unix-like platforms; a good rule of thumb is to _either_ pass the first argument as a list of tokens, or use `shell=True`, but never both. Annoyingly, the behavior on Windows is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

The [shell keyword parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) will be of help, but do note, the documentation does recommend using the [subprocess32 module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/) on POSIX systems.